# Batch script to get Office Version 2019

Tags: batch-file, version

I have been using the code that others have shared and I would like to thank them but I dont know who did it.
But I have code that works great and gets me all the Office versions but I cannot get it to do Office 2019.

I am hoping someone knows the extra line to add to make it work....

When I run it on pre 2019, it is fine. But on 2019, it comes back with Desktop.

```
    cls
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%O in ('ftype ^|findstr /r /I "\\OFFICE[0-9]*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "verp=%%~O"
    goto :end_for
)
:end_for

for %%P in (%verp%) do (
    set "off_path=%%~dpP"
    for %%V in ("!off_path:~0,-1!") do (

     set "office_version=%%~nV"
     goto :end_for2
    )
)
:end_for2

if [%office_version%] == [] echo No Office installed & goto end
echo %office_version%

:end
endlocal

pause

@
TimeOut /t 5 1>Nul

pause
```

Comment: A lot of us are probably not on Office 2019 yet so it would help if you could help us debug your code by letting us know what is getting output from each for command and what is getting assigned to each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be interested to know what the following adapted code outputs. It was written for earlier versions of Office, and I have made a guess at what change to make for the newest version.

```sh
@Echo Off & Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0" & Exit /B)
Set /A "OSA=MWB=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"
If %OSA% Equ 86 Set "MWB=32"
Set "REG=%__AppDir__%reg.exe"
Call :Chk
If Not Defined MOB If %MWB% Equ 64 Call :Chk \Wow6432Node
If Not Defined MOB (Echo Microsoft Office product not installed & GoTo EndIt
) Else If Not Defined IOV (Echo Unable to determine Microsoft Office version
    GoTo EndIt)
Echo %MWB%-bit OS with an Office %IOV% %MOB%-bit product installed in %OIL%

:EndIt
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F "Tokens=1,2" %%G In ("!CMDCMDLINE!"
) Do Endlocal & If /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" If /I "%%~H" == "/c" Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Chk
Set "GUID=" & Set "IOV=" & Set "MOB=" & Set "OIL="
Set "Key=HKLM\Software%1\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%REG% Query "%Key%" /K /F "*-001B-*0FF1CE}" 2^>NUL'
) Do Set "GUID=%%~nxG" & GoTo Next

:Next
If Not "%GUID:~-1%"=="}" Set "GUID="
If Not Defined GUID Exit /B
Set "MOB=32" & If "%GUID:~20,1%" == "1" Set "MOB=64"
If "%GUID:~4,1%" == "2" Set "IOV= 2007"
If "%GUID:~4,1%" == "4" Set "IOV= 2010"
If "%GUID:~4,1%" == "5" Set "IOV= 2013"
If "%GUID:~4,1%" == "6" Set "IOV= 2016"
If "%GUID:~4,1%" == "7" Set "IOV= 2019"
For /F Tokens^=2* %%G In ('%REG% Query "%Key%\%GUID%" /V "InstallLocation"
 2^>NUL') Do Set "OIL=%%H"
If Not Defined OIL Set "OIL=an unknown location"
Exit /B
```

*Please note, that this was designed to use the data for Microsoft Word, because I decided that everyone who installs Office would always install Word. It should therefore work with Word 2007 onwards, and any Office version from 2007 onwards, (with Word installed as a component).

Comment: Compo Thank you for your script and suggestions. When I run the script it comes back with no Microsoft Product not installed.

Comment: Thanks for trying it, @doheth, could you please report back the output from the following two commands, both run from a Command Prompt window? `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /K /F "*-*0FF1CE}" /Reg:64` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /K /F "*-*0FF1CE}" /Reg:32`

Comment: @combo L:\>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /K /F "*-*0FF1CE}" /Reg:64
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90160000-007E-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90160000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90160000-008C-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90160000-008C-0411-1000-0000000FF1CE}

Comment: It appears that the GUID numbering scheme has changed, so I'm going to have to do some research to try to identify when and how things have changed. For what you've provided from my current information, you have 64-bit RTM Volume License Editions of Office 2016 Products most probably in en-US and ja-JP languages. There seems to be little information currently available, so it may take me a some time to figure this all out, and I may have to rewrite my code almost entirely. It would assist me, if you could upload somewhere the registry values and data from those three keys for me to assess.